# Want to calculate the difference from values on 2 different rows using python or pyspark

Tags: python, list, arraylist, pyspark

everyone:

So I have this list type object in python:

```
[[10, 542.5354710621561],
 [200, 11.802396794545745],
 [700, 1.561175174358397],
 [2000, 0.20926429043267342],
 [10, 1107.0197845783787],
 [200, 24.2886201681616],
 [700, 3.1771001799962972],
 [2000, 0.4405625905369205]]
```

What I need to do is to loop by group and calculate the difference of **200-10** and **11.802-542.535**. Then, calculate **700-200** and **1.561-11.802**. finally, calculate **2000-700** and **0.209-1.561**. I would have to do the same for the second group.

My desired output is:

```
{ID_10000_10_200: float_value_here, ID_10000_200_700: float_value_here, ID_10000_700_2000: float_value_here, ID_20000_10_200: float_value_here, ID_20000_200_700: float_value_here, ID_20000_700_2000: float_value_here}
```

Could you suggest the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is ID_10000_10_200 a placeholder for 190 (200-10)?

Comment: How are you defining the `id_10000` or `id_20000` section, do these ID numbers matter?

Comment: Yes, the numbers 10000 and 20000 matter but I can add them to the list: ``` [[10000, 10, 549.7374891412558],
 [10000, 200, 11.606709354357797],
 [10000, 700, 1.6392354197665262],
 [10000, 2000, 0.2042362064342665],
 [20000, 10, 1361.9743632614627],
 [20000, 200, 22.664201537351765],
 [20000, 700, 3.0681569263316266],
 [20000, 2000, 0.5177459808387871]] ``` and no ID_10000_10_200 would be the placeholder for the result of the formula d= 2*((log(200)-log(10))/(log(542.535)-log(11.802))), for example

Comment: You've identified the steps to carry out; where is your attempt to code those steps?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `range()` to iterate over your list and calculate values based on the previous index. Since you did not specify which value you want to store, i calculated both and stored them in a `tuple` in the final result.

```
data = [[10000, 10, 549.7374891412558], [10000, 200, 11.606709354357797], [10000, 700, 1.6392354197665262], [10000, 2000, 0.2042362064342665], [20000, 10, 1361.9743632614627], [20000, 200, 22.664201537351765], [20000, 700, 3.0681569263316266], [20000, 2000, 0.5177459808387871]]

result = {}

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    d_id = f'ID_{data[i][0]}_{data[i - 1][1]}_{data[i][1]}'
    calculations = (data[i][1] - data[i - 1][1], data[i][2] - data[i - 1][2])
    result[d_id] = calculations
```

Outputs:

```
{'ID_10000_10_200': (190, -538.130779786898), 'ID_10000_200_700': (500, -9.96747393459127), 'ID_10000_700_2000': (1300, -1.4349992133322598), 'ID_20000_2000_10': (-1990, 1361.7701270550285), 'ID_20000_10_200': (190, -1339.310161724111), 'ID_20000_200_700': (500, -19.59604461102014), 'ID_20000_700_2000': (1300, -2.5504109454928394)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
nums_list = [[10, 542.5354710621561],
             [200, 11.802396794545745],
             [700, 1.561175174358397],
             [2000, 0.20926429043267342],
             [10, 1107.0197845783787],
             [200, 24.2886201681616],
             [700, 3.1771001799962972],
             [2000, 0.4405625905369205]]

nums_list = [nums_list[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(nums_list), 4)]
final_diffs_object = {}
for y in range(len(nums_list)):
    for x in range(1, len(nums_list[y])):
        diff = nums_list[y][x][0] - nums_list[y][x - 1][0]
        diff2 = nums_list[y][x][1] - nums_list[y][x - 1][1]
        final_diff = diff - diff2
        print(final_diff)
        final_diffs_object["ID" + "_" + str((y+1) * 10000) + "_" + str(nums_list[y][x - 1][0]) + "_" + str(nums_list[y][x][0])] = final_diff
print(final_diffs_object)
```

Sample output:

```
{'ID_10000_10_200': 720.7330742676104, 'ID_10000_200_700': 510.24122162018733, 'ID_10000_700_2000': 1301.3519108839257, 'ID_20000_10_200': 1272.7311644102172, 'ID_20000_200_700': 521.1115199881654, 'ID_20000_700_2000': 1302.7365375894594}
```